# Using mysql's\mariadb's root user for development on a docker development environent running multiple application instances

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I have setup a docker-based development environment having the following images as you can see in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:

 phpBB_dev:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    args:
      XDEBUG_HOST: 172.17.0.1
      XDEBUG_PORT: 9021
      UID: 1000
      GID: 1000
  image: 'pcmagas/phpbb_dev'
  links:
    - mariadb
    - postgresql
  volumes:
    - "$SRC_PATH:/var/www/html:Z"
    - "$SRC_PATH_3_1_10:/var/www/phpBB_3_1_10:Z"
    - "$SRC_PATH_3_0_14:/var/www/phpBB_3_0_14:Z"

 nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "5092:5092"
    - "5093:5093"
    - "5094:5094"
  links:
    - "phpBB_dev"
  volumes:
    - './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
    - './logs/dev/nginx:/var/logs'
  volumes_from:
    - 'phpBB_dev'

 mariadb:
  image: mariadb
  volumes:
    - './db/maria:/var/lib/mysql'
  ports:
    - '5434:5432'
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'phpp_unsafe_passwd'

 postgresql:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
    - './db/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
  ports:
    - '3306:3306'
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'phpp_unsafe_passwd'

 adminer:
  image: adminer
  links:
    - 'mariadb'
    - 'postgresql'
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
```

I use the tool `adminer` in order to setup tables etc etc for my databases. And I have this question:

Is it good idea to use the `root` user as the one that the applications (guess ;) ) I currently develop to use it in order to connect into the database or is recommended to create a user for a specific application instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of taste somehow but in general the autorisation mechanisms are there to use them.

Meaning: If at all possible use granularity and create distinct users with minimum permissions for each task.

If anything goes wrong you can revoke permissions for one task without disturbing the others and an account with minimal permissions is minimal dangerous.

The root credentials should not be spread all around.